# Showing sms conversation(inbox+sent),For that using Loadmanager; It is not working

Tags: java, android, load

I am showing the conversation of sent+inbox messages,fetching that and showing in listview,whenever a new message comes or if i will send one message to that number.I am provide to write message also below to reply.Those messages are not showing at that time itself,for that i need to go back and come to this activity.then only the message is showing.

I want to show immediate one,for that i used loadmanager but is not working.its not showing any error also.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.message_box);

        messagelist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSMS);
        send = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.send);
        tempelates = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tempelates);
        typemsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.typemsg);
         reqnum = getIntent().getExtras().getString("contactname");
        String messgid = getIntent().getExtras().getString("threadid");

           Cursor c= getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null,  "thread_id=" + messgid, null, null);
           ArrayList<String> body = new ArrayList<String>();
           ArrayList<String> msgtype = new ArrayList<String>();
           ArrayList<String> timing = new ArrayList<String>();
           ArrayList<String> newtime = new ArrayList<String>();
           ArrayList<String> newdate = new ArrayList<String>();
           ArrayList<String> newmonth = new ArrayList<String>();
           ArrayList<String> newcheck = new ArrayList<String>();

           if(c.moveToFirst())
           {
               do

               {
                   String address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
                  body.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString());
                     String getdate=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")).toString();
                     System.out.println("dteee"+getdate);

                     msgtype.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")).toString());
                     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
                     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                     Long timestamp = Long.parseLong(getdate);
                     calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
                    newcheck.add(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));

                     System.out.println("check time"+newcheck);
                    SimpleDateFormat tmp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:yyyy");
                     Calendar calendar11 = Calendar.getInstance();
                     Long timestamp1 = Long.parseLong(getdate);
                     calendar11.setTimeInMillis(timestamp1);
                     newdate.add(formatter.format(calendar11.getTime()));

                    //String datee = tmp.format(calendar.getTime());

                     SimpleDateFormat tmp1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                     Calendar calendar12 = Calendar.getInstance();
                     Long timestamp12 = Long.parseLong(getdate);
                     calendar12.setTimeInMillis(timestamp12);
                     newtime.add(formatter.format(calendar12.getTime()));

                     SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM:dd:yyyy"); 
                     Calendar calendar13 = Calendar.getInstance();
                     Long timestamp13 = Long.parseLong(getdate);
                     calendar13.setTimeInMillis(timestamp13);
                     newmonth.add(formatter.format(calendar13.getTime()));


                     //timing.add(newcheck);


               }while(c.moveToNext());
           }
           else
           {
               System.out.println("Nomsg");
           }

           mAdapter = new MyAdapter(IndividualMessages.this,body,msgtype,newtime,newmonth);
           messagelist.setAdapter(mAdapter);
           getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(URL_LOADER, null, this);

           send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
           {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

        String msg =typemsg.getText().toString();

                if(msg.length()>140)
                  {for(int i=0;i<=msg.length()+1;i++)
                  {
                   try
                   {

                String nowgoingmsg=msg.substring(i,i+140);

                  SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                  sms.sendTextMessage(reqnum,null,nowgoingmsg,null, null);


                  i=i+139;
                   }
                   catch(Exception e)
                   {
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                    String nowgoingmsg=msg.substring(i,msg.length()-1); 
                    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    sms.sendTextMessage(reqnum,null,nowgoingmsg,null, null);

                    break;
                   }
                  }
                  }
                  else
                  {
                   try
                       {
                        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                     sms.sendTextMessage(reqnum,null,msg,null, null);

                       }catch(Exception e)

                       {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("unale to send the message-----------------");
                       }
                 }


                restoreSms(reqnum,typemsg.getText().toString());
                typemsg.setText("");
                finish();

            }

            private boolean restoreSms(String messagenumber,
                    String messagebody) {
                boolean ret = false;
                try {
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put("address", messagenumber);
                    values.put("body", messagebody);
                    Uri msguri=Uri.parse("content://sms/sent" );

                    IndividualMessages.this.getContentResolver().insert(msguri, values);
                    ret = true;
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ret = false;
                }
                return ret;

            }


           });

    }


    public void OnBackPressed()
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,MessageListTabActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
        finish();
    }


    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
    {  
        private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
        ArrayList<String> body; 
        //ArrayList<String> timing; 
        ArrayList<String> msgtype; 
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        TextView tv1,tv,receive,sent;
        LinearLayout l1,l2;
     ArrayList<String> newtime;
     ArrayList<String> newmonth;

        MyAdapter(IndividualMessages individualmessages, ArrayList<String> body, ArrayList<String> msgtype,ArrayList<String> newtime,ArrayList<String>newmonth)
        {
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(body.size());
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)IndividualMessages.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            this.body = body;
            this.msgtype = msgtype;
            this.newtime = newtime;
            this.newmonth = newmonth;


        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return body.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View vi=convertView;
            if(convertView==null)

            vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.individual_message_row, null); 
            l1=(LinearLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.chat1_area);
            l2=(LinearLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.chat2_area);
            tv= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.chat1_text);
            tv1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.chat2_text);
            receive= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.receive);
            sent= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.sent);


            try
            {
                if(msgtype.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                {
                    l1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    receive.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv.setText(body.get(position));
                    receive.setText("Received:"+newtime.get(position)+","+newmonth.get(position));
                   l2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    tv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    sent.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {
                    l2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    sent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv1.setText(body.get(position));
                    sent.setText("Sent:"+newtime.get(position)+","+newmonth.get(position));
                    l1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    receive.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
            catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){

            }


            return vi;
        }
        public void swapCursor(Object object) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    }


     @Override
     public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor c) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      //mAdapter.changeCursor(arg1);
         mAdapter.swapCursor(c);

     }

     @Override
     public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
     }



     @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    @Override
     public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
       CursorLoader cu = null;

       switch (id) {
             case URL_LOADER:
                 cu= new CursorLoader(IndividualMessages.this,uri,null,null,null, "date desc");
                    String messgid = getIntent().getExtras().getString("threadid");
               Cursor c= getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null,  "thread_id=" + messgid, null, null);
               final ArrayList<String> body = new ArrayList<String>();
               final ArrayList<String> msgtype = new ArrayList<String>();
               final ArrayList<String> newcheck = new ArrayList<String>();
               final ArrayList<String> newtime = new ArrayList<String>();
               ArrayList<String> newdate = new ArrayList<String>();
               final ArrayList<String> newmonth = new ArrayList<String>();
               if(c.moveToFirst())
               {
                   do

                   {
                       String address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
                      body.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString());
                         String getdate=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")).toString();
                         msgtype.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")).toString());
                         SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
                         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                         Long timestamp = Long.parseLong(getdate);
                         calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
                        newcheck.add(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));

                         System.out.println("check time"+newcheck);

                         SimpleDateFormat tmp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:yyyy");
                         Calendar calendar11 = Calendar.getInstance();
                         Long timestamp1 = Long.parseLong(getdate);
                         calendar11.setTimeInMillis(timestamp1);
                         newdate.add(tmp.format(calendar11.getTime()));

                        //String datee = tmp.format(calendar.getTime());

                         SimpleDateFormat tmp1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
                         Calendar calendar12 = Calendar.getInstance();
                         Long timestamp12 = Long.parseLong(getdate);
                         calendar12.setTimeInMillis(timestamp12);
                         newtime.add(tmp1.format(calendar12.getTime()));

                         SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM:dd:yyyy"); 
                         Calendar calendar13 = Calendar.getInstance();
                         Long timestamp13 = Long.parseLong(getdate);
                         calendar13.setTimeInMillis(timestamp13);
                         newmonth.add(month_date.format(calendar13.getTime()));

                   }while(c.moveToNext());
               }
               else
               {
                   System.out.println("Nomsg");
               }
              IndividualMessages.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                          mAdapter = new MyAdapter(IndividualMessages.this,body,msgtype,newtime,newmonth);
                           messagelist.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                         sms.clear();

                      registerForContextMenu(messagelist);
                    }
             });
                 default:
                 // An invalid id was passed in

         }
      return cu;

     }
```

I used extends of fragment activity too